# Number type with accuracy information?

Tags: python, floating-accuracy

Recently someone wanted a collision-free hash function to hash a million values to a 32-bit hash value. If you know the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), you know that's unlikely to be collision-free. But wanting to know the probability, I computed it like this (start with probability 1, then for each of the million values, multiply with the probability that it's none of the previous):

```
>>> p = 1
>>> for i in range(10**6):
        p *= (2**32 - i) / 2**32

>>> p
2.7390147476139603e-51
```

But I'm multiplying a million floats there, so I'm worried about losing more and more accuracy.

Is there a number type which, unlike simple floats, gives me not just an inaccurate number but also tells me how inaccurate it is? Like a range like `[2.73e-51, 2.74e-51]` or with an error like `2.7390147476139603e-51 +/- 1e-54`?

Or is there some other way to check the accuracy of the result?

Comment: You are looking for [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) and related concepts. A web search shows [this](https://pyinterval.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [this](https://fabricesalvaire.github.io/python-interval-arithmetic/) Python implementation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, turned that into an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63265561/13008439).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [commented by Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264446/number-type-with-accuracy-information?noredirect=1#comment111872143_63264446), that's "[interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) and related concepts".

Googling [python interval arithmetic](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=python+interval+arithmetic) finds [PyInterval](https://pyinterval.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Let's try that:

```
from interval import interval

p = interval[1]
for i in range(10**6):
    p *= (2**32 - i) / 2**32
print(p)
```

Output (run [on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/RedundantFelineAttribute#main.py)):

```
interval([2.7390147473969355e-51, 2.739014747831127e-51])
```

Let's compare that with the bounds from the [integer calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63264447/13008439):

```
interval upper 2.739014747831127e-51
integer upper   27390147476140722271150280539996691121583143640960
integer lower   27390147476140722271150280539996691121583143636646
interval lower 2.7390147473969355e-51
```

So the `interval` solution is less precise (it's a larger interval, only the first ten digits of lower and upper bound match), but it's correct (the real value is indeed inside the interval). I guess it'll always be correct in that sense, though I didn't look into how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a worst case: on every operation (multiply or divide), explicitly multiply the result by 1+2^-52 or 1-2^-52 and check (using `assert`) that it actually made a difference.  This should estimate an upper bound for the uncertainty, and it is still pretty small -- it reaches the end without any assertions failing, and the difference is one part in 10^9.

```
import sys

m_upper = (1 + 2**(1 - sys.float_info.mant_dig))
m_lower = (1 - 2**(1 - sys.float_info.mant_dig))

p_upper = p_lower = 1

for i in range(10**6):

    factor = (2**32 - i) / 2**32
    f_upper = factor * m_upper
    f_lower = factor * m_lower

    assert(f_upper > factor)
    assert(f_lower < factor)

    p_upper *= f_upper

    p_upper1 = p_upper * m_upper
    assert(p_upper1 > p_upper)
    p_upper = p_upper1
    
    p_lower *= f_lower

    p_lower1 = p_lower * m_lower
    assert(p_lower1 < p_lower)
    p_lower = p_lower1

print(p_upper, p_lower, p_upper - p_lower)
```

Gives

```
2.739014748809663e-51 2.7390147464186476e-51 2.3910154124504752e-60
```

Note that if the `(1 - sys.float_info.mant_dig)` is replaced by `-sys.float_info.mant_dig` (i.e. use 2^-53 instead of 2^-52) then assertions start to fail.

Comment: I don't quite understand it yet (will think about it more), but the reason it fails with `(1 + 2**(-sys.float_info.mant_dig))` is that that's just 1. But you can stil use it for `m_lower`, just not for `m_upper`.

Comment: @superbrain Thanks - I didn't test. My point is that the value used was as far as I could push it by this (fairly conservative) technique. There may of course be better techniques that will achieve a narrower range.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you counteract rounddown errors by going to a larger number and roundup errors by going to a smaller number, right? Now I'm considering installing Python 3.9 just to try out its [math.nextafter](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/math.html#math.nextafter) for this...

Comment: Yes, that was my basic idea. My assumption is that any such errors only affect the last bit provided that you are only doing one operation at a time, so that if you go up/down enough to get a different value, then that is enough to counteract them. Hope this is valid!

Comment: Yes, I agree it's valid, and I actually [did it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63266009/13008439) with math.nextafter now. Gives me a *slightly* narrower result interval.

Comment: @superbrain Yes, I completely failed to take into account that the factors themselves are accurate. So we can just use `factor` in place of `f_upper` and `f_lower` - now getting `1.174665825232771e-60`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get a range is to use integers, scaling the probability by let's say 10<sup>100</sup>. For the lower bound always round down, and for the upper bound always round up:

```
>>> lower = 10**100
>>> for i in range(10**6):
        lower = lower * (2**32 - i) // 2**32

>>> lower
27390147476140722271150280539996691121583143636646
```

```
>>> upper = 10**100
>>> for i in range(10**6):
        upper = -(-upper * (2**32 - i) // 2**32)

>>> upper
27390147476140722271150280539996691121583143640960
```

Aligning them:

```
upper  27390147476140722271150280539996691121583143640960
p     2.7390147476139603e-51
lower  27390147476140722271150280539996691121583143636646
```

We can see that `p` (the `float`) is actually outside the real range, a bit too small. But its first twelve digits are correct, so that seems pretty good.

By comparing `lower` and `upper`, we also get quite a few more matching and thus correct digits: 2.73901474761407222711502805399966911215831436e-51. And with a larger scaling factor, we can get even more.

Answer (score 0):

(Based on [alaniwi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63264891/13008439))

The factors `(2**32 - i) / 2**32` are accurate, i.e., they're represented as `float` exactly. Furthermore, the floating point standard guarantees that multiplications result in the most accurate `float` value. It might be lower or higher than the real product, but it's the closest `float` value possible. So if we intentionally always deviate to the next larger `float` value, that'll never be smaller than the real value, i.e., it gives us an upper bound. And we get a *lower* bound by deviating to the next *smaller* `float` value.

Python 3.9 introduces [math.nextafter](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/math.html#math.nextafter), let's use that:

```
>>> import math
>>> lower = upper = 1
>>> for i in range(10**6):
        factor = (2**32 - i) / 2**32
        lower = math.nextafter(lower * factor, -math.inf)
        upper = math.nextafter(upper * factor, math.inf)

>>> lower, upper
(2.739014747179961e-51, 2.739014748048138e-51)
>>> upper - lower
8.681767916298978e-61
```